# discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "balance" is not found error even though its there

Tags: discord, discord.py

I am trying to make a discord.py bot with an economy system, this is the basic script which shows the balance.

```py
client.command()
async def balance(ctx):
    global user

    await open(ctx.author)
    users = await get()

    wallet_data = users[str(user.id)]["wallet"]
    bank_data = users[str(user.id)]["bank"]

    details = discord.Embed(title=f"{ctx.author.name}'s balance now", color=discord.Color.red())
    details.add_field(name="W A L L E T", value=wallet_data)
    details.add_field(name="B A N K", value=bank_data)

    await ctx.send(embed=details)


async def open(user):
    global users

    users = await get()
    
    with open(r"C:\discbot\bank.json", "r") as data:
        users = json.load(data)
    
    if str(user.id) in users:
        return False
    
    else: 
        users[str(user.id)]["wallet"]=0
        users[str(user.id)]["bank"]=0
    
        with open(r"C:\discbot\bank.json", "w") as data:
            json.dump(users,data)
    
        return True


async def get():
    with open(r"C:\discbot\bank.json", "r") as data:
        users = json.load(data)

    return users


client.run(ID)
```

It however returns with

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "balance" is not found
```

Even though balance is defined when I run it.

Comment: Can you put `@` to the beginning of `client.command()`?

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `@client.command()` before your `async def ...` to register it as a command.

```py
@client.command()
async def foo(ctx):
    await ctx.send("bar")
```

Also, you re-define open. So your `async def open` function will be recursive when called, and will error.